# Android -> iOS zero conf network discovery with jmDNS broken

Tags: android, ios, bonjour, service-discovery, jmdns

I'm using jmDNS 3.4.1 to do network discovery between Android and iOS. Recently it has not worked properly. The Android app broadcasts itself on the network using mDNS. The iOS app looks for services using NSNetServiceBrowser. iOS does discover the Android service, but when I attempt to resolve the service, resolve fails (just times out, no error). During this time the Android spits the following out to Logcat:

`W/DNSIncoming(14994): There was an OPT answer. Not currently handled. Option code: 65002 data: DE4710F674B73176`

This may have to do with iOS 8. I'm not sure. The same code worked on iOS 7. Does anyone know what the problem is, how to fix, or whether there is a jmDNS fork that fixes this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching to Android's native network discovery (NsdManager) this is no longer a problem. It seems to be an incompatibility between jmDNS and iOS 8 / OS X 10.10.